# What could be used to associate these fairing halves with their launches?

Tags: spacex, failure, identify-this-object

Eric Ralph's Teslarati article [SpaceX’s BFR factory in LA spied with four Falcon 9 fairing halves](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-bfr-factory-four-falcon-9-fairing-halves-spied/) shows several panoramic photos of the site for the future rocket factory. In it, the author says:

> From left to right, my best guess for each fairing is PAZ, Iridium-6 Half 1, Iridium-5, and Iridium-6 Half 2.

**Question:** What visual cues or other information could be used to associate each of these already-used fairing halves with their launches? Are there hidden markings, or other distinctive features?

Open these large images in a new window to view them full size:

**below x2:** from [Teslarati](https://www.teslarati.com/spacex-bfr-factory-four-falcon-9-fairing-halves-spied/). Photo credit: Pauline Acalin

[image: SpaceX airing halves - Teslarati]

[image: SpaceX airing halves - Teslarati]

Comment: Great question! Where did the quote for ‘best guesses’ come from?

Comment: @Jack I've moved the quote up one line.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed the image caption on the article. As far as I know, the missions stated are some of the only ones where a successful (water landing) of a fairing has been achieved? Unfortunately the branding for the payloads would be on the underside in the image, so I'm not sure how they've been identified beyond guess-work and maybe clues to how long they've been there?

Comment: @Jack I see. Slightly related items: [1](https://imgur.com/a/0bo6s), [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/whatisthisthing/comments/2dgyiw/found_on_the_beach_on_cape_hatteras_nc_looks_to/), [3](https://www.instagram.com/p/BfgRX-lgIt6/) Also, it's in the second sentence of the article, as well as in the caption.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can you find out how many times a SpaceX fairing has been reused?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/63001/how-can-you-find-out-how-many-times-a-spacex-fairing-has-been-reused)

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch no, because 1) the answer doesn't even answer that question, but more importantly 2) Whatever procedures are in place now would not apply to a photo **5 years ago**. We don't vote to close questions just because they are similar somehow to other questions, there has to be an expectation that an answer will be there. So much has changed in five years, no answer to that question is going to answer this, so it's not a helpful vote to close.

Comment: But isnt it that the question exists and has answers, even if it was later? @Fred

Comment: @Starshipisgoforlaunch I don't exactly agree with Fred - we can close forward or backward in time, whichever way is likely to point readers to the best and most appropriate answers to the closed question. For example answers to questions about Newton's laws will be fairly timeless. But in this particular case answers about modern fairings are not going to apply to these very old, unique fairings, flown before SpaceX started any standard procedures. So in this case closing as duplicate does harm rather than help.

Comment: Okay then @uhoh